# Hbase: How to know if a row had particular column family or not?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Let's assue that rowkey 1 has values for f1:c1, f1:c2
Where as rowkey 2 has values for f1:c1 only. row 2 doesn't have f1:c2.

How do i recognize such rows(the ones without column populated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to know from row then try like this...

  ```
   HTable t = new HTable(conf....);
   ResultScanner scanner = t.getScanner(new Scan());    
   for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) 
   {
         if (rr.getValue("YourFamily" , "YourQualifier").equals(Bytes.toBytes("d"))
         {
          // do some thing
         } else { return; // if you want to skip     } } }
  ```
- See [Result](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html)

`result.getFamilyMap()` is one more way. But its not recommended due to performance.. see the doc of this method

However, [HTableDescriptor.html](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HTableDescriptor.html) has already hasfamily method.

```
boolean hasFamily(byte[] familyName)
Checks to see if this table contains the given column family
```